# turn sprite list images into single images for use

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

so trying to make this as simple as I possibly can (which is next to impossible)

so in the unity editor using the 2d platformer learning thing im trying to switch the player sprites with many sprite lists from https://aamatniekss.itch.io/fantasy-knight-free-pixelart-animated-character for the images I'm trying to make the images into a new sprite animation

I hope I made this straight forward enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [BRACKEYS TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&t=596s)

You need to make sprite sheets or create the animations in the Unity animation system and then trigger them by code or state machine.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87cF8jqVpBA
i found it myself so anyone who needs to know here you go
make sure the sprite isnt in single but multiple.